# Rule based ISLE Ensemble Generation

Tags: machine-learning, cart, supervised-learning, ensemble-learning

I come through a algorithm **ISLE Ensemble Generation** in machine learning. The following is the steps given in *Elements of Statistical Learning*: 
[image]

But I am unable to apprehend it and implement it in python program. Can anyone explain this algorithm using an example.So that I am in a state to implement it in program.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone still need this answer for an important lost algorithm.

It is implemented here:
https://github.com/yq911122/isle

Additionally, I suggest reading the paper:

`Importance Sampled Learning Ensembles
Jerome H. Friedman, Bogdan E. Popescu
September 9, 2003`